# How to shift one specific bullet to the right

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, itemize

I am trying to shift one specific bullet to the right in an `itemize` environment. All threads I see are about shifting the entire list to the right. `\item[\qquad]` and `\item[\hspace*{5cm}]` and `\item[\phantom{anything}]` doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: `\item[\hspace*{5cm}\textbullet]` probably works but it seems a very strange thing to do how is the reader supposed to interpret this? Is it really a one-item nested list?

Comment: No, it doesn't work @DavidCarlisle. `\item[\hspace*{5cm} What I want to write]` and `\item[\hspace*{15cm} What I want to write]` gives the same space.

Comment: I am actually trying to have a small heading somewhere in the middle of the document. But I already have a running list of two items before, so I thought of adding this as another item in the same list for indentation convenience.

Comment: How about making that item a nested list:
\begin{itemize}
\item What I want to write
\begin{itemize}
\item What I want to write2
\end{itemize}
\item What I want to write3
 \end{itemize}

Comment: "it doesn't work" well we have to guess as you have shown no code, it is hard to tell you how to customise your list format when you have given no indication of your current format. Questions almost always are clearer if they contain a complete small test document, but as ferstad just says if the result is going to look like an indented nested list the most obvious markup is as a nested list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** as others have noted in the comments, this is a strange thing to do. I don't recommend it. Nevertheless...

In an itemized list, you can imagine a vertical line between the bullets (or other symbols) and the items themselves. The bullets are right-justified against this line. The following example demonstrates this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbullet\textbullet\textbullet] abc
\item def
\item ghi
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: list1]

I can think of two dirty hacks which will push one item to the right. First, push everything else to the left!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\item[\textbullet\quad] def
\item[\textbullet\quad] ghi
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: list2]

Alternatively, cancel the symbol for the indented item, and place it to the right of the vertical line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] \textbullet\hspace{\labelsep} abc
\item def
\item ghi
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: list3]

Comment: Thank you, nice answer!